# Is there a way to check the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" is activated?

Tags: javascript, laravel, browser

I had a project which is export a csv file and update the download time in admin page and it's worked normally when the browser **Ask where to save each file before downloading** is disabled. But just for example if the administrator accidentally turn it on then it will create a bug.

The bug : If he/she pressed cancel then my ajax code will still return success call and the download time will be updated despite no files are downloaded
[Bug Occur when press this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlgSz.png)

I don't know if there is a way to check if the **Ask where to save each file before downloading** is activated or not ?

I'm using Laravel 8 btw , and here is my JS code :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSBHx.png)

Comment: please paste your controller code of download file

Comment: this hack should work for you [Detect when browser has received the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)

Comment: @user1994 No need friend because the problem is not about I can't download file. It's about how can I check if the person browser has the  'Ask where to save each file before downloading' is turn on or not :)))

Comment: @s.wadhwa it's look promising :))) thank you ! I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through browser-native FS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem)

(Works with Chrome and maybe Firefox)

So first you'd do your ajax call to get the CSV file into JavaScript, and then use the BNFS. BNFS generates a user abort exception if the user clicks cancel, so then maybe you'd need to send a message back to the server saying that the download was aborted

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . May I ask what is BNFS is ? Because I can't seem to find it on the internet .

Comment: @Harron BNFS is short for Browser Native File System